# f.input rows not working Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rows, simple-form, formbuilder

Using simple form and f.input on my rails 4 app, however, the row amount is not working. Displays 1 row only.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@article) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :whyrating, :input_html => { :rows => 5 } %>

<% end %>
```

also tried without input_html

```
<%= f.input :whyrating, label:"Why it deserves this rating", :rows => 5 } %>
```

Does anyone no the reason why? I'm sure it's something simple but can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: What about f.text_field  or f.text_area

Comment: Yeah just went with text_area and it worked fine. Having trouble understanding when to use which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with `f.text_area` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating "<%= f.input :whyrating, label:"Why it deserves this rating", :rows => 5 } %>" you can use "<%= f.text_area :whyrating, label:"Why it deserves this rating" } %> in rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input_html attribute of the form input to specify the number of rows. Moreover, in Rails 4+ you can simplify your code such as:

```
<%= f.input :whyrating, input_html: { rows: "5" } %>
```